# How can I set focus to a div with overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

When I go to the Gallery page of this website: http://roxannelin.azurewebsites.net I am unable to scroll down until after I click on the page. I would like to be able to scroll down using the mouse wheel as soon as I land on this page.

I have tried setting the focus by placing a tabindex on the div and using jquery .focus() however this moves me to the 3rd tab (showreel) and messes up the layout.

How can I bind the scroll event to this particular div without the user having to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use click trigger on your div or on any element inside your div, after DOM load:

```
$(function() {
    $("#divId").trigger("click");
});
```